# I want to modify this code in order to bring only those were the class industry = "auto"

Tags: php, jquery, html, jquery-ui, multi-select

I have a jQuery code that brings all the attributes from one side of a panel to another. This button works as an "Add All". The following code makes that happen.

So far I've done some modification in order to suit my purpose. The following code that I tried still works as an "Add All"

It keeps bringing me all the values from one table to another instead those where industry = auto.

This is the original "Add All" Code.

```
this.container.find(".add-all").click(function() {
            var options = that.element.find('option').not(":selected");
            if (that.availableList.children('li:hidden').length > 1) {
                that.availableList.children('li').each(function(i) {
                    if (jQuery(this).is(":visible")) jQuery(options[i-1]).attr('selected', 'selected'); 
                });
            } else {
                options.attr('selected', 'selected');
            }
            that._populateLists(that.element.find('option'));
            return false;
        });
```

This is what I've tried so far...

```
this.container.find(".add-auto").click(function() {
            var options = that.element.find('option').not(":selected");
            var elements = $('li').find("[industry]")
            if (that.availableList.children('li:hidden').length > 1) {
                that.availableList.children('li').each(function(i) {
                    if (jQuery(this).is(":visible") && jQuery(this).find("[industry = 'auto']")) jQuery(options[i-1]).attr('selected', 'selected');
                });
            } else {
                that.availableList.children('li').each(function (i) {
                    if (jQuery(this).find("[industry = 'auto']")) jQuery(options[i-1]).attr('selected','selected');
                });
            }
            that._populateLists(that.element.find('option'));
            return false;
        });
```

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example I suspect that some of your loops are confusing `this`. Also I do not see where `that` is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Without better context, it's hard to know what is not working for you. The only thing I can see as an issue is confusing `this` in your `.each()`.

Consider the following:

```
this.container.find(".add-auto").click(function() {
  var options = that.element.find('option').not(":selected");
  var elements = $('li').find("[industry]")
  if (that.availableList.children('li:hidden').length > 1) {
    that.availableList.children('li').each(function(i, el) {
      if (jQuery(el).is(":visible") && jQuery(el).find("[industry='auto']")){
        jQuery(options[i-1]).attr('selected', 'selected');
      }
    });
  } else {
    that.availableList.children('li').each(function (i, el) {
      if (jQuery(el).find("[industry='auto']")){
        jQuery(options[i-1]).attr('selected','selected');
      }
    });
  }
  that._populateLists(that.element.find('option'));
  return false;
});
```

If we pass in the Index (`i`) and the Element (`el`), we can ensure there is no conflict of `this`.

Hope that helps.